# I want to create methods to search, edit, and erase arrays in a list. Does anyone have any tips or examples?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I have an assignment where I need to create a blog where people can create, search and display all posts (arrays). But for a higher grade i need to create methods for searching for, editing, and erasing said posts. Are there any tips for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class which has an array inside it.
You create a list of objects of your class
Then you create an object of that class with the needed Array infos and put it in your list

```
    class Posts
    {
        public string[] Text;
    }
```

```
List <Posts> posts = new List<Posts>();

Posts NewPost = new Posts();

NewPost.Text[] = "Your text"

posts.Add(NewPost);
```

Comment: Am I able to do it without creating the array in the class? I know it's easier but the teacher wants us to create a list containing arrays, but I'm not allowed to build the program around a list containing classes sadly.

Comment: yes you can. You can create a list of the string array type. You cant have multiple variables bound to your List now. You can than just add your array (string[] test;) to your list (List <string[]> posts = new List<string[]>();) If my answer help me pls give it a upvote or mark it as answer

Comment: thank you for your help! I don't have enough reputation to upvote sadly